# No project to import - For google-play-services_lib

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, google-play-services

Am trying to import google-play-service library in my workspace for developing google map application.

i follow these steps,

1. In sdk manager i downloaded playstore lib
2. I checked in android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib and also found library file
3. while importing i am getting error message that no project to import
4. i tried clean the workspace, restart the workspace also.
5. i am using API 21, System config 64-bit

I search a lot for same problem but I cant get a proper solution. i dont know where i am wrong. please help me where i am wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

one possibility are there

this message arise when your project already imported

so try it to create new work-space and then import it will be imported.